# Cakephp 3 subquery expressions

Tags: select, expression, conditional-statements, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to create conditional select here based on type field. Why `$exp->addCase()` call is invalid and it says, that `addCase()` is unknown method?

```
$query->select(function ($exp) use ($query) {
    $concatPerson = $query->func()->concat(['lastname' => 'literal', ', ', 'firstnames' => 'literal']);
    return $exp->addCase(
        [
            $query->newExpr()->eq('type', 1),
            $query->newExpr()->eq('type', 2),
        ],
        [$concatPerson, 'business_name'],
        ['string', 'string']
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because callables for `select()` do not work the same way as callables for `where()`. Callables for `select()` are invoked with the current query passed to them (ie you are calling `addCase()` on a query object), and they are expected to return a list of fields to select.

What you are trying to do requires to directly pass expression objects to `select()`, like

```
$concatPerson = $query->func()->concat([
    'lastname' => 'literal', ', ', 'firstnames' => 'literal'
]);
$exp = $query->newExpr()->addCase(
    [
        $query->newExpr()->eq('type', 1),
        $query->newExpr()->eq('type', 2),
    ],
    [$concatPerson, 'business_name'],
    ['string', 'string']
);

$query->select(['field_alias' => $exp]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Case statements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements)**